# number is a string in a csv?

Tags: pandas, csv, int

I have just read several answers about the frequently asked error message,

`TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int`

The problem is that all of them were based on the input() command. My problem is that I am trying to compare values in a csv file, as shown here:

```
math_mavens = []
for row in complete_data_pd:
    if "math_score" >= 70:
        math_mavens.append("student_name")
num_math_mavens = len(math_mavens)
percent_math_mavens = num_math_mavens / total_students
```

I got that the string must be cast as an int, but I don't understand how to do that in this instance, where there is no input(). The numbers (or strings) are coming directly from a csv.

Comment: Is `complete_data_pd` a dataframe? and `math_score` a column? If so you can just do this to get your percent_math_mavens: `len(complete_data_pd[complete_data_pd['math_score'] >= 70])/total_students`

Comment: Yes, Ben Pap, that is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one posted a separate answer, I here repost Ben Pap's comment as the answer that worked:

Is complete_data_pd a dataframe? and math_score a column? If so you can just do this to get your percent_math_mavens:

```
len(complete_data_pd[complete_data_pd['math_score'] >= 70])/total_students
```

– Ben Pap Jan 21 at 22:21